# Django Template - Increasing the value of a variable in a template in a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to display a rank against each item I'm looping over in a for loop in a Django template. I'm initially displaying 10 items on the page and loading 10 more items each time the load more button is pressed.

I tried using the `{{ forloop.counter }}` but that works only for the first 10 items. Since the call involves AJAX, each time new items are appended they have ranks from 1-10.

I can send a `rank` variable to the template, but I need a method that increments that `rank` variable by 1 each time in the for loop. Is there any default Django filter for this? Or can anyone help me write a custom filter for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up combing the `{{ forloop.counter }}` and the `rank` variable using the add filter.

```
{{ forloop.counter|add:rank }}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `rank` integer already, you can simply use the existing [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to add the counter:

```
{{ forloop.counter0|add:rank }}
```

Comment: That's what I just figured out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My idea will be to create a counter class that you will used to increment your rank

```
class Counter:
    counter = 0    
    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.counter
    def set_to_zero(self):
        self.counter = 0
        return self.counter
```

and pass it in the context.
Then each times you are in your loop you can increment it with

```
{{ counter.increment }}
```

Comment: This outputs the string "None" into my template whenever I call {{ counter.increment }}

Comment: @Moritz That's because he forgot to return anything